# MATLAB - identification of every typesetted symbol

Tags: matlab

I have the following code in MATLAB, where the user has to enter the word `"precipitations"` letter by letter. After typing one letter, the user has to press **Enter** and the program checks, whether the typed letter was correct.

Now I would like to change the program, such that the user does *not* have to press **Enter** after typing a letter. Is there any operator or function in MATLAB which reacts to every pushed button, so one does not have to press **Enter**?

```
disp('Please enter "precipitations" without errors')
target=('precipitations');
n=size(target); n=n(2); % Characters number

for i=1:n;
    YourInput(i)=input('','s');
    if YourInput(i)==target(i)
        disp('OK. Please, input the next symbol')
        i=i+1;
    else
        disp('Error. Please try again.')
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: I changed quite a lot in the text to make it (in my opinion) more easily understandable. If you are not ok with those changes, feel free to do a rollback. You do that by clicking on the `edited x min ago` below the question, going down to your last revision and pressing `rollback`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is *no* built-in MATLAB function to do this. There is however a function `getkey` on [MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7465-getkey).

You can download this function and change your code to use

```
YourInput(i) = getkey();
```

--

I of course wondered how this can be achieved, and it does the following: They create a new figure with a window size of `0,0` at position `(1,1)`. You'll notice the new figure at the bottom left of the screen.

Then, a callback function `KeypressFcn` which is executed whenever a key is pressed, is created. The pressed key is saved in the `UserData` field of the figure, and returned as variable. The interesting parts of the function (and a minimal example) are:

```
fh = figure(...
    'keypressfcn','set(gcbf,''Userdata'',double(get(gcbf,''Currentcharacter''))) ; uiresume ', ...
    'position',[0 0  1 1] ...
);
uiwait ;
key = get(fh,'Userdata') ;
delete(fh) ;
```